# How to fix Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foreach') and response.json is not a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am figuring out what's the problem with my code but I can't look the right answer. I am getting this error:

```
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') at renderUsers (forReviewCtrl.js:16)`
```

and this error

```
   `TypeError: response.json is not a function
    at getUsers (forReviewCtrl.js:7)
    at renderUsers (forReviewCtrl.js:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (forReviewCtrl.js:36)`.
```

I don't understand. Please someone can explain to me why because I am new to javascript.

Here is the code:

```
angular.module('newApp').controller('forReviewCtrl', function(){

    function getUsers() {
        let url = '/tm-swagger-postman.json'; //API
        try {
            let response = fetch(url);
            return response.json(); //error
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    async function renderUsers() {
        let users = await getUsers();
        let html = '';
        users.foreach(user => {               //the error
            let htmlSegment = `<table border="3px;">
            <tr>
            <td>"${user.fname}"</td>
            <td>"${user.last}"</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>"${user.fname}"</td>
            <td>"${user.last}"</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>`;
    
            html += htmlSegment;
        });
    
        let container = document.querySelector('.container');
        container.innerHTML = html;
    }
    
    renderUsers();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting some `async` and `await` keywords.  Since you're trying to `await` the call to `getUsers()`, make that function `async`:

```
async function getUsers() {
  //...
}
```

Then within that function, `await` the asynchronous operations:

```
let response = await fetch(url);
return await response.json();
```

Comment: I still get this error ` TypeError: users.foreach is not a function
    at renderUsers (forReviewCtrl.js:16)` .. I don't know why

Comment: @Gheh: `users` might not be an array.  What is it?  Just before trying to use it, do `console.log(users)` and what gets logged to the console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the `fetch(url)` before being able to call `.json()` on it. Currently, you're trying to call `.json()` on the promise itself, not the result of it.

Try this:

```
function getUsers() {
    let url = '/tm-swagger-postman.json'; //API

    return fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```